# ADO.NET SqlParameter Object

Tags: sql, ado.net, sybase, inequality, sqlparameter

I'm working in C#, and trying to work with a Sybase database via ADO.NET.  The database is currently being interacted with via NHibernate.  I have declared the SqlCommand object "cmd" and am attempting to convert three different types of queries.  I am using the following approach:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@et.enrtype_id", sp.enrtype_id);
```

Which I believe is adding the parameter that "et.enrtype_id is equal to sp.enrtype_id".
However, I need to change the following SQL statements:

"a.eff_start_dt is not null"

"a.eff_stop_dt is null"

And any statements involving inequalities (>, <, >=, <=, !=)

How would I go about including the inequality information in the ADO.NET statements?  I've done a ton of research online and can't find it anywhere.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: about NULL: add an IF statement and if it's true cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@et.enrtype_id", DBNull.Value );

Comment: @JoeTaras okay, so, like, 

if(et.enrtype_id == NULL)

{

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@et.enrtype_id", DBNull.Value);

}
?

Comment: Yes, my dear. In the else put your initial statement